# How do I make a plate wrap around the edge of the object?

Tags: bezier-curves, edges, shrinkwrap

[Project on the google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sO3BdTF_JDLogd7630CFttAlGz4yhGqV/view?usp=sharing)[image][image][image]

Hi. I need to make this object wrap around the model. I tried using a shrinkwrap modifier. However I wasn't able to make it to bend the plate. Does it have to do with lack of vertical loopcuts? (I can't add them because of a weird topology). I also tried using a subdiv, but it didn't change anything. What should I do to achieve the bending around that edge effect?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand how you shape looks like and what you're trying to achieve, could you please show a picture of your object model?

Comment: I added additional pictures

Comment: your topology is super messy, what you could do is use a Curve modifier in order to bend your object, but make sure that your object has enough topology to bend